# Samsung galaxy S5 display and touch not working

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

my samsung galaxy S5 android 6.0.1 not starting. only **task manager touch key light** keeps always on. but touch not working. and display not working. can anyone suggest me a solution for this issue.

What i have already Tried :

- Remove battery and insert it again, but not succeed.
- start device by pressing volume down and power key but not succeed.